# How to not display signals on my shell?

Tags: c, shell, signals

I'm actually trying to do a shell. That's a school project. It works perfectly but I wanted to handle signals (like `^C` and `^D` for example).

So I used the **signal.h** lib (I'm on Maverick OS), and it seems to work properly, my shell won't quit. But it still is a little problem.

The `^C` is still displayed on my term, and I don't want it to be displayed.

I used the signal function: `signal(SIGINT, do_nothing);`

The `do_nothing` function contain:

```
void  do_nothing(int sig)
{
  if (sig)
  {
      ;
  }
}
```

How can I delete the signal characters?

Comment: What do you mean by `delete signal character` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether your program handles signals or not, the terminal driver has its own behavior.  For instance (see the [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcsetattr.3.html) manual page), the `ECHOCTL` setting is relevant:

```
       ECHOCTL
          (not in POSIX) If ECHO is also set, terminal special
          characters other than TAB, NL, START, and STOP are echoed as
          ^X, where X is the character with ASCII code 0x40 greater than
          the special character.  For example, character 0x08 (BS) is
          echoed as ^H.  [requires _BSD_SOURCE or _SVID_SOURCE]
```

To see what your program actually needs, you should start by becoming familiar with the *canonical* mode described in `termios` versus alternatives such as *raw* mode.  Note that these are built up from a variety of (sometimes) interrelated settings.  So you might start by just modifying existing settings to change the feature that you are interested in.

Comment: Unfortunately for this project i'm not allowed to use the canonical mode.

But thanks for the answer.

Comment: The *canonical* mode is essentially the default terminal settings.  As you may find in the code-sample below, it is a starting point which you may discard completely or amend - but a basic understanding of it will be needed to make those changes reliably.